# Passing a URL as a GET parameter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, url

I am trying to make a bookmarklet that uses the user's current URL, kind of like the tinyURL bookmarklet that uses this javascript code

```
javascript:void(location.href='http://tinyurl.com/create.php?url='+location.href)
```

So I copied that same thing and made

```
javascript:void(location.href='http://mywebsite.com/create.php?url='+location.href)
```

Then I use:

```
$url=$_GET['url'];
```

to retrieve it. The problem is, if I am on a url that already has some get style info in the url, it messes everything up.

Example, If I am on:

```
http://www.google.ca/webhp?um=1&hl=en&safe=off
```

The '_GET' code sets $url to be

```
http://www.google.ca/webhp?um=1
```

So I think the info in google URL is messing up all of my URL parsing, I imagine I am doing something very incorrectly or someone has a very elegant solution for this. What should I do? please help

Comment: How come you stripped `&hl=en&safe=off` but not `um=1`?

Comment: @NullUserException: I suppose this is because of that `?` already exists in the URL and browser/server might treat the second one as "normal" char.

Answer (score 18):

[URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url) has a specified format. That part after `?`, or to be more exactly between `?` and `#` if exists, is called [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Querystring). It contains a list of key-value pairs - a variable name, `=` character and the value. Variables are separated by `&`:

```
key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3&key4=value4
```

You should escape `location.href` as it *can* contains some special characters like `?`, `&` or `#`.

To escape string in JavaScript use [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function like so:

```
location.href = "http://tinyurl.com/create.php?url=" + encodeURIComponent(location.href)
```

It will replace characters like `&` into `%26`. That sequence of characters isn't treated as a variable separator so it will be attached as a variable's value.

Comment: Thanks, seems easy enough. What is the proper way to decode this in PHP then?

Comment: You don't have to. `$_GET['url']` will contain the proper value, ie. `http://..../...html?abc=def&ghi=123`. However PHP comes just like JavaScript does with several functions for URL escaping: [`urlencode()`](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

Comment: @MikeD I know it is a little bit old, but I think you should accept this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
javascript:void(location.href='http://mywebsite.com/create.php?url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
javascript:void(location.href='http://mywebsite.com/create.php?url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href))
```

You need to escape the characters.

Answer (score 0):

so what are you wanting, just the url without the query string?

```
$url = explode('?',$_GET['url']);
$url = $url[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass url in $_GET parameter like this:

```
http://yoursite.com/page.php?myurl=http://google.com/bla.php?sdsd=123&dsada=4323
```

then you need to use encode function:

```
echo 'http://yoursite.com/page.php?url='.urlencode($mylink);

//so, your output (url parameter) will get like this
//http://yoursite.com/page.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2Flink.php%3Fname%3Dsta%26car%3Dsaab
```

after that, you need to decode the parameter with:

```
$variab = $_GET['url'];
$variab = preg_replace("/%u([0-9a-f]{3,4})/i","&#x\\1;",urldecode($variab)); 
$variab = html_entity_decode($variab,null,'UTF-8');
echo $variab;
```

such way, you can pass the correct link as a parameter.