# Pass URL as $_GET variable?

Tags: .htaccess, get

I currently have my own URL Shortening service.

How would I go about writing the .htaccess file so that if you go to `http://www.xxxxx.com/shorturl` it'll treat the `shorturl` as the shortened url (instead of a directory) and pass it on to the `decoder.php` file as a `$_GET` variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following in a `.htaccess` file in the web root of your server, it's a pretty standard use of `mod_rewrite`. If it already exists with some other `Rewrite` rules just tack the block on to the end of your `.htaccess` file without the `RewriteEngine On` bit.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Turn on the rewrite engine
    RewriteEngine On

    # If the page doesn't really exist, run it through decoder.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule /?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ decoder.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: hmph...no luck. Let's just say that the shortened URL is http://www.xxxx.com/hEkr

Would it get passed through as http://www.xxxx.com/decoder.php?id=hEkr

Comment: @Jason: Yes, that's correct. You'll need to change the GET parameter name to what your `decoder.php` is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [mod_rewrite](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite). Information abounds at your favourite search engine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15642716/2131877

there you will see how to endoce url before you send that as a $_GET parameter, because the special symbols of link `=&://` has to be encoded before they are passed.