# Difficulty passing GET variable?

Tags: php, html, sql, get

Hi I am trying to display specific entries in a database by appending the variable name to a URL like:

```
echo '<td><a class="index_table" href="includes/view.php?id=$row[id]>$row[Orderno]">
```

and then in my view.php I have:

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
//Display the Data//
$id=$_GET['id']; 
$result=mysql_query("select * from Products where ID=$id");
$row=mysql_fetch_object($result);
echo "<table>";
echo "
<tr bgcolor='#f1f1f1'><td><b>ID</b></td><td>$row->ID</td></tr>
```

However the specific ID is not being passed to the script, and the table in view.php is blank. When changing the where clause to 'where id = '1' the correct product displays. So I know that this is working.

Many Thanks

Comment: but I suppose you acces it by : `http://site.com/view.php?id=23` right?

Comment: @w0rldart we all hope so....

Comment: What if I pass this parameter: includes/view.php?id=1%20or%20true

Comment: Also it's vulnerable to sql injection

Most answers contain SQL injection! Take care with that! 

You need first to cast $id as and integer!

Comment: What happens when i decide to send this to your server
`includes/view.php?id=1%3BDROP%20TABLE%20PRODUCTS%3B` ?

Comment: I think the problem is that **you arent encoding the $_GET parameter**. View this topic:
**http://stackoverflow.com/a/15642716/2131877** because you need to encode the parameters to pass it as one variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basic PHP syntax: Strings quoted with `'` do not interpolate variable values:

```
echo '<td><a class="index_table" href="includes/view.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '>' . $row['Orderno'] . '">';
                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

note that you're wide open to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) and are just begging to get your server pwn3d.

Answer (score 2):

**First problem:**

You have to put the array string indexes into a paranthesis:

```
echo '<td><a class="index_table" href="includes/view.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['Orderno'].'</a></td>';
                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**Second problem:**

Your ID in the URL could easily be replaced with `'; DELETE FROM table #` thus allowing an attacker to perform a SQL injection! Always sanitize any user input (POST) or GET parameters that takes a part in SQL queries:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
```

or for that case (when an integer is expected)

```
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];
```

**Suggestion:** do not use `mysql_*` functions but use `PDO` with (real!) prepared statements or at least `mysqli_*` functions with proper input sanitization.

Answer (score 1):

Two big issues here.  First, your link is not working correctly because you are using single-quotes in your echo, meaning the variables are not interpolated, so you must change to something like either of the following:

```
echo "<td><a class=\"index_table\" href=\"includes/view.php?id={$row['id']}>{$row['Orderno']}\">";
```

or

```
echo '<td><a class="index_table" href="includes/view.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '>' . $row['Orderno'] . '">';
```

### WARNING - SECURITY BREACH

In your later code you are leaving yourself open to SQL Injection attack; some references to what this is can be found at [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection), and are very important to learn about.  To protect yourself, you must escape data before sending it to a query.  Here are some ways to do that:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']); 
$result=mysql_query("select * from Products where ID = '$id'");
```

or

```
$id = $_GET['id']; 
if (!ctype_digit((string)$id)) {
    die('Invalid ID: ' . htmlentities($id));
}
$result=mysql_query("select * from Products where ID = '$id'");
```

In the first example, I use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to make the data safe for embedding in a query (note that I also added quotes around the variable); in the second, I did a data check to make sure it contained only digits (note that the length should also be checked, but this is a quick example), and if it contained something other than digits, we spit out an error message and don't run the query.

Comment: Why would you escape by hand ??? PHP supports prepared statements, there is no reason I can think of to escape by hand over prepared statements...

Comment: Submitter is already using the old mysql driver, we don't know what his/her environment looks like, whether PDO is installed, or what capabilities s/he has to do upgrades, if any.  It is far and away simpler to answer in the style that solves the problem(s) at hand without completely shifting paradigms -- if I was chatter with the submitter face-to-face, I'd recommend PDO in a second, but this format does not lend itself too well to such things.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query like, I added two `'` between $id

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from Products where ID='$id'");
```

And see.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually including the value of the $id variable in the query. Take a look at this answer for options on how to do this:

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection)

PDO

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = :name');

$stmt->execute(array(':name' => $name));

foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

mysqli

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put the `GET` variable directly into the query like that, you should do some sanity checks like checking it's numeric etc. to avoid sql injection.

No doubt you will have answers saying the `mysql_` functions are deprecated aswell but I don't think that's relevant to the question.

In your link you have

```
<td><a class="index_table" href="includes/view.php?id=$row[id]>$row[Orderno]">
```

you don't have the right syntax for the array elements, try

```
<td><a class="index_table" href="includes/view.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '>' . $row['Orderno'] . '">
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a malformed URL in the  tag, plus PHP doesn't parse variables in single quoted strings. I think you just need this:

```
echo "<td><a class='index_table' href='includes/view.php?id=$row[id]'>$row[Orderno]</a></td>";
```

You don't need to change the code in view.php but I would recommend filtering the _GET variable this way:

```
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo "<td><a class='index_table' href='includes/view.php?id=".$row['id'].">".$row['Orderno']."'>";
```

and

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
//Display the Data//
$id=$_GET['id']; 
if(is_int($id))
{
    $result=mysql_query("select * from Products where ID=$id");
    $row=mysql_fetch_object($result);
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr bgcolor='#f1f1f1'><td><b>ID</b></td><td>$row->ID</td></tr>";
}
else
{
    echo "<h1>Nice try silly... You aint hackin me!</h1>";
}
```

I also noticed in your original code you were missing some ending quotes and semi-colons. That may have been all that was wrong. But this should clear up your security issue and should work for your application

Good luck.