# reHow to send a set of string in single variable through url

Tags: html, jsp

I want to send a value in URL that value contains more than one words i am using the given concept for example

`<a href=page.jsp?variable1=value1&variable2=value2>click here</a>`

Suppose in above value `value1=aa` and `value2=bb cc dd` 
but in the url of `page.jsp` i am getting `value1=aa` and `value2=bb` only and the rest value "`cc dd`" is missing.

what should i do to get complete value for example value2=bb cc dd

I am giving here my code after making it more simple to focus on desire problem

```
`<%
        MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
        DB database = mongo.getDB("studentDB");
        DBCollection collection = database.getCollection("AskQuestion");
        DBCursor cursor = collection.find();
        String bodycontent="";

        while(cursor.hasNext())
        {       
            DBObject str=cursor.next();             
            bodycontent+="<table><tr><td><div><a href=Answer.jsp?ObjectID="+str.get("_id")+"&Title="+ str.get("TITLE") +"> "+ str.get("TITLE") +"</a></div></td></tr></table>";
        }
        out.print(bodycontent);
        %>`
```

For example str.get("_id") gives value "55093da9223da86a0212b364" and
str.get("TITLE") gives value "Question Title" .
Now my problem is i got value in Answer.jsp for str.get("TITLE") is only "Question" but not "Title" and i want the full value i.e Question Title.
I hope i am clear with my problem.

Comment: May i know how did you stored the values such as `bb cc dd` in variable value2 ?

Comment: According to my requirement  i am fetching the value bb cc dd from mongoDB database.

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding your second variable and then attach it.

example: `bb%20cc%20dd`

```
<a href=page.jsp?variable1=value1&variable2=bb%20cc%20dd>click here</a>
```

You need to use java script for encoding your URL see this question for more details.

[Passing a URL as a GET parameter in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540184/passing-a-url-as-a-get-parameter-in-javascript)

**Edit**

See these answers

[How to URL encode a URL in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15923062/how-to-encode-my-url-in-jsp/15926416#15926416)

http://www.coderanch.com/t/521213/JSP/java/encoding-URL-href-element-JSP

Comment: Yes its working in this case but what should i use if the value bb cc dd is coming from database and i have to check this string  for equality in another page with another string